# Algorithm/Puzzle

Tags: algorithms

You have a three by three of squares with one black marble placed randomly in one of the nine squares. Distance between squares is measured as one if either diagonal or horizontal/vertically next each other, and two otherwise. In all squres a distance of one from the randomly placed black marble, there are blue marbles. In all remaining squares there are red marbles (distance of two from black marble). All marbles are covered by identical cups. Develop an algorithm that finds the black marble in the fewest number of attempts. An attempt include looking under a single cup and seeing the color of that marble. What is the average number of attempts it will take for your algorithm to find the black marble? Assume there is an equal probability of the black marble being in any square.

We can draw the picture. For instance suppose the black marble is in the bottom left corner. Then we have 3  blue marbles around it and 5 red marbles around the blue. My algorithm starts always by picking the middle cup and looking under it. If it's black we're done. It cannot be red! because the middle one is 1 away from everything. So it must be blue. Then we pick a cup at a random corner. It's either the black one or the red one. We keep picking corners until we find our marble. If we hit a blue marble in a corner we look at a cup right next to it. Not sure if this is the right strategy. The most number of picks required to find the marble is 5 i think from this strategy. Any help?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Surely you can come up with some algorithm for this.

Comment: I added my thought process. Can you help further?

Comment: Ok.  First note that the problem does not call for the optimum algorithm, so you could just do the analysis on the one you proposed.  Good exercise!  That said, it seems clear to me that this one is sub-optimal.  Why?  Well, you win on the first try with probability $\frac 19$ (as you would with any guess) but if you fail then you get no information as you already know it is either black or blue.  If, instead, you started at a corner then you learn a lot even if it isn't black.  Similarly, you learn a lot if you start on the side.  I'd analyze all three cases.

Comment: I see. I think the best one is if you start on the side i think, not the corner.

Comment: You may be right.  My initial thought is that they are the same (as a non-black answer divides the other $8$ up as $3,5$ in both cases).  But I have not thought it through so I may well be wrong.  Anyway, go with it.  Start with a side choice.  Write out the decision tree and do the calculations.  This should not be a terribly difficult computation.

Comment: I am posting an analysis of your "start with the side" algorithm below which you can compare to what you are working on.  As I say,  nothing here shows it is optimal.  I suggest working out the "start with a corner" algorithm along the same lines to compare.

Comment: There are at most $9 \times 9!$ ways this game can be played out (9 possible starting boards and 9! move sequences).  Just check all of them.

Comment: Why do you keep blanking parts of your question? If it is accidental, please be more careful before pressing the **DELETE** or **BACKSPACE** button, and check before pressing the **SUBMIT** post button. If it is **not** accidental, then you better stop doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us analyze the corner-first approach. I use the same labelling as lulu's,
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & C \\
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

1. $A$ is black, good.
2. $A$ is blue. Then the black marble is at $B,D$ or $E$. We test $I$: if $I$ is blue, then the black marble is at $E$; if $I$ is red with test $B$.
3. $A$ is red. Then the black marble is at the right or bottom part of the board. We test $I$: if it is black, we are fine. If it is blue, we need to test $F$, then $H$ if $F$ is blue. If I is red we need to test $C$, then $G$ if $C$ is red.

$A$ takes one guess. $I$ takes two. $B,C,E,F$ take three. $D,G,H$ take four.
Here the average number of guesses is exactly $3$, so lulu's approach is better.

---

Corner-first, version 2.

1. $A$ is black, good.
2. $A$ is blue. Then the black marble is at $B,D$ or $E$. We test $D$: if $D$ is black, fine. Otherwise $D$ is blue: we test $B$, then $E$ if needed.
3. $A$ is red. Then the black marble is at the right or bottom part of the board. We test $I$: if it is black, we are fine. If it is blue, we need to test $F$, then $H$ if $F$ is blue. If I is red we need to test $C$, then $G$ if $C$ is red.

$A$ takes one guess. $D,I$ take two guesses. $B,F,C$ take three. $E,H,G$ take four.
Here the average number of guesses is  $2.888$, like in lulu's approach.

---

Center-first:

1. If $E$ is black, fine. If $E$ is blue, we look at $D$.
2. If $D$ is black, fine. If $D$ is blue then the black marble is at $A,B,G$ or $H$. We look at the color of $F$ and with at most two extra lookups we find the black marble. If $D$ is red, the black marble is at $C,F$ or $I$. We test $I$ first: if $I$ is black we are done, if $I$ is blue the black marble is at $F$ and if $I$ is red the black marble is at $C$.

$E$ takes one guess. $D$ takes two guesses. $I$ takes three. $F$ takes three guesses. $A,B,C$ take four.  $G,H$ take five. An average of $3.444$ guesses, even worse than before.

---

Side-first, but with a twist.

1. We guess $B$. If it is black, fine.
2. If $B$ is red the black marble is at $G,H$ or $I$. We test $I$ first. If $I$ is not the black marble, we know where the black marble is between $G$ and $H$.
3. If $B$ is blue we test $H$, which cannot be black. If $H$ is red, we test $C$. Then if $C$ is not the black marble, the black marble is at $A$. If $H$ is blue we test $F$. If $F$ is not the black marble we know where it is between $E$ and $D$.

$B$ takes one guess. $I$ takes two guesses. $G,H,C,F$ take three. $A,D,E$ take four.
An average of $3.333$ guesses. Testing a position where we know the black marble cannot lie does not seem to be efficient.

---

**The Shimari approach**.

There is a little plot twist if we just need *to know where the black marble is*, without removing its cap. In such a case, by just testing $A,F,H$, we either find the black marble among $A,F,H$ or we collect enough information to know where the black marble is (see the attached table). $A$ takes one guess, $F$ takes two guesses, any other position takes three, with an average of $2.666$ guesses which beats lulu's approach.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline A & F & H & \text{black marble}\\ \hline \text{blue}&\text{blue}&\text{blue}&E\\ \hline
\text{blue}&\text{blue}&\text{red}&B\\ \hline
\text{blue}&\text{red}&\text{blue}&D\\ \hline
\text{red}&\text{blue}&\text{blue}&I\\ \hline
\text{red}&\text{blue}&\text{red}&C\\ \hline
\text{red}&\text{red}&\text{blue}&G\\ \hline\end{array}$$

Comment: can you describe how you compute the average number of trials?

Comment: I think i got it. 1/9 (1x1 + 1*2 + 4 *3 ...) = 27/9

Answer (score 3):

Here is one algorithm:

For specificity, let's label the cells as 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & C \\
    D & E & F \\
    G & H & I \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Let us begin by guessing $B$.

Case I:  $B$ is black.

Case II:  $B$ is blue.  Then the correct answer is one of $\{A,C,D,E,F\}$  Start by guessing $D$.

IIa.  $D$ is black.

IIb.  $D$ is blue.  Then the correct answer is either $A$ or $E$.  Guess $A$ first.

IIc.  $D$ is red.  Then the correct answer is either $F$ or $C$.  Guess $F$ first.

Case III.  $B$ is red.  Then the correct answer is one of $\{G,H,I\}$.  Guess $H$ first (it can only be black or blue).

IIIa.  $H$ is black.

IIIb.  $H$ is blue.  Then guess $G$ first.

Analysis:  $B$ takes one guess.  $D,H$ take two guesses.  $A,F,G$ take three.  $E,C,I$ take four.  Thus the expected number of guesses using this algorithm is $$\frac 19 \times (1\times 1+2\times 2+ 3\times 3+3\times 4)=\frac {26}9=2.888\dots$$

Comment: I don't think IIc.is possible as E cannot be red. Additionally, it is better to still check another side rather than the middle again because if we find a red in the side it will narrow down the problem a lot. Finally, what is your rationale for picking one side over another?

Comment: The sides are symmetric, it makes no difference which one we start on.  You are correct on your other points, I forgot how diagonals work.  So, yes.  My choice of $E$ is not good.  Better to go with one of the others.

Comment: I have edited in an attempt to fix the prior blunder.  I have to run out, and I (strongly) suggest checking carefully lest I have left some blunders in place or added new ones.